# Update loop renews object instead of removing it

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm stuck on a bug that I can't figure out. I have an update loop that's supposed to run each object through its 4 phases (spawning, alive, dying, dead) and then remove it from the arraylist. After it does that, it should refill the arraylist with a new object.

This works sometimes. Other times instead of removing the object just as the lifespan of the last phase almost runs out, it refreshes the last phase's lifespan. This happens intermittently with 2 or more sprites - sometimes they get removed properly, other times the behaviour described above takes place. I'm not really sure why it's happening. Here's my code:

```
    elapsedTime = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

    //update sprite phases and lifespans; if dead remove from array 
    if (mSprites != null) {
        Iterator<ESprite> i = mSprites.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            ESprite s = i.next();
            float ls = s.phase.getLifeSpan();
//          l.error("Sprite id: "+s.id+". Sprite phase: "+s.phase+". Sprite phase timespan: "+ls);
            if (s.phase == Phase.DEAD && ls <= 0) {
                i.remove();
            } else if (ls > 0) {
                s.phase.setLifeSpan(ls-=elapsedTime);
            } else {
                s.nextPhase();
            }
        }
    }

    //spawn new sprites if needed
    if (mSprites != null) {
        while(mSprites.size < numOfSprites) {
            mSprites.add(spawnRandomSprite());
        }
    }
```

Here's the snippet for nextPhase():

```
public void nextPhase() {
    if (this.phase != Phase.DEAD) {
        phaseIndex++; /* 0-3 */
        this.phase = phases[phaseIndex];
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
public class ESprite extends Sprite {
public int id;
private Random r = new Random();
public Phase phase;
public Phase[] phases = new Phase[]{Phase.SPAWNING, Phase.ALIVE, Phase.DYING, Phase.DEAD};
public int phaseIndex = 0;
public enum Phase {
    SPAWNING,ALIVE,DYING,DEAD;
    private long lifeSpan;

    public void setLifeSpan(long lifeSpan) {
        this.lifeSpan = lifeSpan;
    }

    public long getLifeSpan() {
        return lifeSpan;
    }

}

public ESprite(Sprite s) {
    super(s);
    phase = Phase.SPAWNING;
    id = r.nextInt(100);
}

public void nextPhase() {
    if (this.phase != Phase.DEAD) {
        phaseIndex++;
        this.phase = phases[phaseIndex];
    }
}
}
```

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: can you show the Phase class please?

Comment: Also, please post how `phases` array is declared and initialized. It is a field of `ESprite`, right?

Comment: Just added code for Phase and ESprite classes

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll edit my answer with the info I now have. You can still look at it in its current state, it should be helpful too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s.phase.setLifeSpan(ls-=elapsedTime);
```

The above line suggests that you want to set the lifespan of a `Phase` object that is dedicated to the current Sprite.

However, `Phase` is an `enum`. There are only 4 instances of `Phase` in your whole program: `Phase.SPAWNING`, `Phase.ALIVE`, `Phase.DYING`, `Phase.DEAD`. This is what an enum means. These instances are shared between your sprites. If you change the lifespan of one of them, all sprites will see the change.

You should not allow any `Phase` to be mutable(*). You should **make the lifespan a property of your sprites**, not a property of `Phase`, because `Phase`s objects are shared among sprites.

(*) it might be useful in some rare cases, but not in yours, you're misusing it here.

Comment: Phase is an enum. Why can't an enum have a changing lifespan? If every ESprite gets its own set of Phases and each Phase gets its own lifespan - it makes sense on paper, no?

Comment: @VeryAttractiveS No. Your `enum` only contains 4 instances of `Phase`, one for each constant. All your `ESprite`s share the same 4 `Phase` objects in their `phases` array. If you set the lifespan of `Phase.DEAD`, then it will be changed for all `Phase.DEAD` occurrences.

Comment: @VeryAttractiveS I reworded my answer using the last information you gave.